# Java MS Access Database Connection without Admin rights

Tags: java, ms-access

For a JAVA project I am working on there is a requirement that I use a Microsoft Access Database running on a computer where I do not have administrative priveleges.

So, I have the Access DB file all ready, and I started doing some research - but everywhere I look mentions the need to use the Admin Tools (or Control Panel) to "setup an ODBC connection", sadly it looks like I don't have access to any of these OS level configurations.

Is there any alternative I could use to access the database without the need to start configuring the Operating System (running Windows XP).

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The connction URL may contain the full ODBC information:

```
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(
     "jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=c:/bd1.mdb"
      );
```

No access to the control panel is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

[Jackcess](http://jackcess.sourceforge.net/) is a pure Java library for reading from and writing to MS Access databases.